# How to send User defined object to controller in ajax/jquery

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

This is my html

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Submit"/>
```

And following is JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#button").click(function () {
                var personalInfo = new Object();
                personalInfo.name = $("#name").val();
                personalInfo.age=$("#age").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "@Url.Action("SubmitForm","Account")",
                    data: 'myPersonalInfo='+personalInfo,
                    success: function () { alert("a"); }
            });
            });
        });

        </script>
```

And following is my controller method

```
public ActionResult SubmitForm(string name,string age) 
        {
            Session["Name"]=name;
            Session["Age"]=age;

            return View();
        }
```

I have to send user defined object (PersonalInfo) to server and get its values to maintain session. How it should be done? Pls help

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the values like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("SubmitForm", "Account")',
            data: { 
                name: $("#name").val(), 
                age: $("#age").val() 
            },
            success: function () { 
                alert("a"); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```